# Firebase android cancel running operation

Tags: android, firebase, task

I'm building Android application integrated with Firebase.

Because firebase operation run on background thread, sometimes I must cancel the operation that I queued in Firebase. For example cancel update password operation. How can I do that?

Comment: There is no generic way to cancel such operations. It also sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to cancel an operation? Isn't that better solved by not sending the password change operation to Firebase in the first place?